# Export large sql files and import to a new database where structure is different

Tags: mysql

I have a database with about 38k rows and its about 5GB big. On Navicat I can either dump the file with structure + data or structure only.

On my new database I have a different structure and whenever I add the sql (structure + data) its getting the old structure. What options do I have?

Comment: Modify the dump to match the new structure, or import it and then modify the structure to match the new one, at least

Comment: How would you expect it to know how to load the old data in the new structure? When you restore a database dump it always recreates the old structure.

Comment: Would it work if I dump the data only?